# macro function in libcurl which return the libcurl version

Tags: c, libcurl

I m developing a c program using libcurl.

when I build my program I can use different version of libcurl.

When I change from version to other (of libcurl) I have to change some blocks in my source code to adapt it to the libcurl version.

I'm looking to add macro in my code which will check the libcurl version and then determine which block of source code to use automatically

Are there a macro function or constant in libcurl which return the libcurl version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See curl/curlver.h (which is included when you `#include <curl/curl.h>`).

You have the following numbers to play.

```
#define LIBCURL_VERSION_MAJOR 7
#define LIBCURL_VERSION_MINOR 26
#define LIBCURL_VERSION_PATCH 0
```

and

```
#define LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM 0x071a00
```

Comment: I would not recommend using that, I recommend curl_version_info() instead as in my separate answer.

Comment: @DanielStenberg That wouldn't protect against compiler errors